# JMeter - Read Next Line Issue

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Hi i am facing a very weird issue.
I have created 5 different thread groups each one is calling different APIs and each one has its own CSV file where it reads the data.

I am using a loop controller in order to iterate some calls and in some as a body parameter i am giving the following:

- ${__CSVRead(${username}.csv,1)}${__CSVRead(${username}.csv,next)}.

The above supposed to read the next line in the CSV file after each iteration. At the first two Threat groups is working fine and is reading the next line of the CSV file. My CSV contains the following lines:

- 1,1024587
- 1,1254585

At the first iteration the parameter that i passed is the 1024587 at the body data of the APi and at the second iteration is the 1254585. This is done with the use of the below ${__CSVRead(${username}.csv,1)}${__CSVRead(${username}.csv,next)}.

The problem is that is working in 3 of my Threat Groups but in other two is keep reading the first line all the time it does not go to the second.

[image]

After each iteration is keep reading the first line of the CSV and not the second one. At the following threat group is the same and is working fine as expected.

[image]

Why is this happening. ??? Is so weird.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 2 columns and 2 rows in your CSV file I believe it's much better, faster and easier to go for [User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) pre-processor:

[image]

It allows you to achieve the same behaviour at the same time avoiding reading the file which causes massive disk IO under the load

[image]

More information: [A Quick Guide to JMeter PreProcessors](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/quick-guide-jmeter-preprocessors)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot derive the root cause of that issue. But as a workaround, you can use the approach used in the following image to read data from CSV files and assigned those data into variables. Later on, you can use those variables to create requests and perform your tests. Make sure that data in the CSV files are compatible with the structure you provide here.As an example

```
test/apipath/1.0.0,userTest1,wtyausjdgdt,hjdhjhdhhdhkjjldii
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. This is what i have . I am reading at the beginning a CSV file that contains one column "username".

Comment: In that case, your approach is the way AFAIU